# MYSQL - 2 left Joins to the same table from 2 separate values without needing to create alias

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to left join the same table (a Mapping table)and whilst I can do this because I am creating an alias(joining to the same table but using a different column value in the first table its repeating the same columns(although they are technically different due to the alias join)

Scenario - I have employee that get assigned a Group, however they may have 2 groups assigned(Determined by a separate column)depending on whether they are marked as Online or Offline.

Emp Table

```
|EMP_ID|Online_Group|Offline_CG|Online |
 :----: :----------: :--------: :-----:
|1234  |99          |Null      |Online |
|1223  |88          |Null      |Offline|
|1446  |Null        |77        |Offline|
```

I am trying to join to a mapping table whereby if Online_Group Value is not Null left join on mapping table, if a match Return all columns from Mapping Table and Offline_Group Value is not Null left join on mapping table, if a match Return all columns from Mapping Table

Mapping Table

```
|OT_1    |OT_2     |OT_3     |OT_4     |
|:------ |:-------:|:-------:|--------:|
|99      |109      |400      |999      |
|77      |Null     |Null     |878      |
```

The closest I have got to is by creating to left joins( I need the data retained in the Emp_table)

```
 select *
 from Emp_Table
 left join Mapping_Table
 on Emp_Table.Online_Group IN(Mapping_Table.OT_1, Mapping_Table.OT_2, 
 Mapping_Table.OT_3, Mapping_Table.OT_4)
 left join Mapping_Table a
 on Emp_Table.Offline_Group
 IN(a.Mapping_Table.OT_1, a.Mapping_Table.OT_2, 
 a.Mapping_Table.OT_3, a.Mapping_Table.OT_4)
```

The Output I get is the below

```
|EMP_ID|Online_Group|Offline_CG|Online |OT_1|OT_2|OT_3|OT_4|OT_1|OT_2|OT_3|OT_4| 
|:-----|:----------:|:--------:|:-----:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|
|1234  |99          |Null      |Online |99  |109 |400 |999 |99  |109 |400 |999 |
|1223  |88          |Null      |Offline|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|1446  |Null        |77        |Offline|77  |null|null|878 |77  |null|null|878 |
```

Ideally I want (I.E no repeating columns from the mapping table

```
|EMP_ID|Online_Group|Offline_CG|Online |OT_1|OT_2|OT_3|OT_4|
|:-----|:----------:|:--------:|:-----:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|
|1234  |99          |Null      |Online |99  |109 |400 |999 |
|1223  |88          |Null      |Offline|null|null|null|null|
|1446  |Null        |77        |Offline|77  |null|null|878 |
```

Comment: Not 2 table copies but one table copy, and both conditions combined using OR.

Comment: Ideally only one copy, however I managed to get the output by first creating a view using an if statement to essentially merge the Online/offline group numbers into one column, then used another view to join to the Mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

The table structure seems a bit unwieldy, but ... you shouldn't need multiple joins.  Use something like IF or CASE to return the group id based on current status, then join to the mapping table.

> ```
> SELECT e.Emp_Id
>        , e.Online_Group
>        , e.Offline_CG 
>        , m.OT_1 
>        , m.OT_2 
>        , m.OT_3 
>        , m.OT_4
> FROM (
>         SELECT Emp_Id
>              , Online_Group
>              , Offline_CG
>              , IF(Online = 'Online', OnLine_Group, Offline_CG) AS GroupID
>          FROM   Emp_Table e 
>      ) e 
>      LEFT JOIN Mapping_Table m ON 
>          e.GroupId = m.OT_1 OR
>          e.GroupId = m.OT_2 OR
>          e.GroupId = m.OT_3 OR
>          e.GroupId = m.OT_4
> ```

**Results:**

> ```
> Emp_Id | Online_Group | Offline_CG | OT_1 | OT_2 | OT_3 | OT_4
> -----: | -----------: | ---------: | :--- | :--- | :--- | :---
>   1234 |           99 |       null | 99   | 109  | 400  | 999 
>   1223 |           88 |       null | null | null | null | null
>   1446 |         null |         77 | 77   | null | null | 878
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59b514be9f684990480e7d1e6d9cd0b7)*

Comment: fantastic, Yes the data isnt ideal and will maybe rethink the table design but this is perfect. I went down this route but struggled to join the the Group_ID column, never thought about the qualifiers like this.

Comment: Yeah, a row based based format might work better and would probably be easier to query.